# problem using pycocotools for Scaled Yolo v4 in pytorch : numpy version dilemma

Tags: python, windows, numpy, yolov4, pycocotools

my setting is

python 3.9
numpy 1.21.0
cuda 10.2

right now i'm having a problem receiving two error messages.

one is :
**ERROR: pycocotools unable to run: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer**

second is :
**ERROR: pycocotools unable to run: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject**

situation is, i looked for closed questions and found the solution.
For first error, **downgrading numpy** was a solution for many people. (down to 1.16.5)

For second error, **upgrading numpy** was a solution for many people. (up to 1.21.0)

So if i upgrade numpy, first problem occurs, downgrade, second problem occurs. Opposite solutions.

I've been trying to solve the first error without downgrading my numpy, but it haven't gone very well.

This is the problem code below.

```
   # Save JSON
    if save_json and len(jdict):
        f = 'detections_val2017_%s_results.json' % \
            (weights.split(os.sep)[-1].replace('.pt', '') if isinstance(weights, str) else '')  # filename
        print('\nCOCO mAP with pycocotools... saving %s...' % f)
        with open(f, 'w') as file:
            json.dump(jdict, file)

        try:  # https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/blob/master/PythonAPI/pycocoEvalDemo.ipynb
# THIS IS WHERE THE CODE STOPS WHEN SECOND ERROR OCCURS
            from pycocotools.coco import COCO
            from pycocotools.cocoeval import COCOeval
            imgIds = [int(Path(x).stem) for x in dataloader.dataset.img_files]
            cocoGt = COCO(glob.glob('../coco/annotations/instances_val*.json')[0])  # initialize COCO ground truth api
            cocoDt = cocoGt.loadRes(f)  # initialize COCO pred api
#THIS IS WHERE THE CODE STOPS WHEN FIRST ERROR OCCURS
            cocoEval = COCOeval(cocoGt, cocoDt, 'bbox')
            cocoEval.params.imgIds = imgIds  # image IDs to evaluate
            cocoEval.evaluate()
            cocoEval.accumulate()
            cocoEval.summarize()
            map, map50 = cocoEval.stats[:2]  # update results (mAP@0.5:0.95, mAP@0.5)
        except Exception as e:
            print('ERROR: pycocotools unable to run: %s' % e)
```

Below is the value and type of each cocoGt, and cocoDt

<pycocotools.coco.COCO object at 0x000002351F4CE6A0>
<class 'pycocotools.coco.COCO'>

<pycocotools.coco.COCO object at 0x000002351F4E58E0>
<class 'pycocotools.coco.COCO'>

**cocoEval = COCOeval(cocoGt, cocoDt, 'bbox')**
I think this part is the most suspicious part in the code
I tried to cover the values (cocoGt, cocoDt) with int but it didn't work displaying an error :
**int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'COCO'**.

below is a part of cocoeval.py which contains the def of **cocoEval = COCOeval(cocoGt, cocoDt, 'bbox')** in case it might be an useful information.

```
    def __init__(self, cocoGt=None, cocoDt=None, iouType='segm'):
        '''
        Initialize CocoEval using coco APIs for gt and dt
        :param cocoGt: coco object with ground truth annotations
        :param cocoDt: coco object with detection results
        :return: None
        '''
        if not iouType:
            print('iouType not specified. use default iouType segm')

        self.cocoGt   = cocoGt              # ground truth COCO API
        self.cocoDt   = cocoDt              # detections COCO API
        self.params   = {}                  # evaluation parameters
        self.evalImgs = defaultdict(list)   # per-image per-category evaluation results [KxAxI] elements
        self.eval     = {}                  # accumulated evaluation results
        self._gts = defaultdict(list)       # gt for evaluation
        self._dts = defaultdict(list)       # dt for evaluation
        self.params = Params(iouType=iouType) # parameters
        self._paramsEval = {}               # parameters for evaluation
        self.stats = []                     # result summarization
        self.ious = {}                      # ious between all gts and dts
        if not cocoGt is None:
            self.params.imgIds = sorted(cocoGt.getImgIds())
            self.params.catIds = sorted(cocoGt.getCatIds())
```

Thank you very much for your time